# Amazon SES Emails are not getting to some servers

Tags: email, amazon-ses, bluehost

I have set up Amazon SES. My domain is verified and my DKIM is enabled and verified.
Emails do send but I have a Bluehost account that does not receive the emails. According to the logs at Bluehost they don't hit their servers at all which implies there is no spam filter in the way.
Has anyone run into this?
All other emails that I have tested have no issues. It appears to be unique to Bluehost but they tell me it cannot be them as it isn't even in their logs.

Is there a way to see the Amazon SES logs so I know where these emails get stopped?. There are no bounces returned or complaints being returned.

Thanks

Comment: Try send email via another mail's server. Example: you have mydomain.com; and you send email from no-reply@mydomain.com via SES. Try send to this address from your mx.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Bluehost does general a log for that and it indicates that the emails are being bounced by the Bluehost filter. Amazon SES servers send out from a long domain string that is considered "miscellaneous" on Bluehost side. 
It is being bounced even if you mask it with a email account from your main domain and therefore @Sergey method won't work.

Will share the solution if I manage to find a fix for this.